# CKEditor drag and drop text copy instead of cut

Tags: javascript, drag-and-drop, ckeditor

Recently I upgraded CKEditor from version 4.4.2 to 4.5.3. I'am missing one method when I'm drag&drop text on version 4.4.2 the drag&drop works like copy and paste (Version 4.4.2: http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cDQri8jFZO) on newer version is working like cut and paste (Version 4.5.3: http://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cDQriNjFZ0)

Is there any possibily to change this behaviour to copy and paste instead of cut and paste?

Comment: Can you provide two working examples for 4.4.2 and 4.5.3?

Comment: I can't is an internal app.

Comment: So just create an example in jsfiddle of that specific thing. It looks like there is some other configuration there which causes this behavior.